Duration of Block After Multiple Failed Login Attempts
I would like to know how long a user gets blocked after 5 failed login attempts in Firebase Authentication. Could you provide specific details on the duration and any configurable options related to this rate limiting?
I couldn't find any documented limit.

Firebase has many mechanisms to protect your app against abuses and as you have already seen, most of them are not so well documented. So if you are worried about security and abuses, I recommend you let Firebase handle them.
If you want to prevent your users from making too many failed attempts when logging in, then I recommend you implement an additional layer of your own. In such a case, you'll have multiple layers of security against abuses.
When it comes to signing up for Firebase, please also note that there is a Sign-up quota present in the Firebase Console:

Which by default is set to 100 per day and it protects your project from abuse, only for new Email/Password and Anonymous accounts that can be created in a day from a single IP address.
Besides all of this, I didn't find a number of seconds/minutes/hours in which Firebase throws "TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER". Anyhow, all limits regarding Firebase Authentication are specified here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits


Hey Hassam. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
